# Show/Hide different images using A ImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, show-hide

I need help to display different images using a single ImageView.

For example:

```
if (string == "OK")
{
    // OK Image
}
else
{
    // KO Image
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(string == "OK"){
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:"ok.png")
}else{
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:"NotOK.png")
}
```

You can check Apple Documentation to see `UIImageView` properties and methods (class reference) [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you save your `UIImage` like this.

```
class YourViewController {

    private let image1 = UIImage(named: "image1")
    private let image2 = UIImage(named: "image2")

    //your functions here
}
```

and use this image in your conditional like this.

```
let singleImageView = UIImageView()
if string == "OK"{
    singleImageView.image = image1
}else{
    singleImageView.image = image2
}
```